# Update existing post with Craigslist API

Tags: api, craigslist

I need to automate adding images to some existing posts via Craigslist API.
The documentation at http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface states:
***Note: If you submit a posting item with the same rdf:about as an existing posting item, the existing posting item will not be updated. Presently the only way to alter the content of a posting is via URL specificed in the cl:postingManageURL element.***
This is pretty vague. The way I understand this is, you  first have to attempt a post, get a URL back and then it's unclear what to do next. 
Has anyone tried this? Ideas?

Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with this API, but when I see this:

```
<cl:postingManageURL> - In post mode, this element will contain a URL that can be used to edit or delete the new posting.
```

That leads me to believe that all you need to do is make sure your request is an HTTP POST with the same `postingManageURL` as the post you want to edit. Then provide the `previewHTML` you want to update the post with.

Comment: I understand that everything is a POST. So the trick is to remember postingManageURL and use it for future updates.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "everything is a POST." You have to configure your REST client to send requests using whichever HTTP verb--GET, POST, etc.--is appropriate.

Comment: I was referring to this line in the API doc: "New postings are submitted to the bulk interface in RSS format with additional craigslist-specific elements via HTTPS POST"

Comment: OK, that's just saying to do a bulk posting (where you submit a bunch of posts at once), you use POST. Your question is about updating an *existing* post, which apparently happens to use POST as well.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, CL does not provide an API to update ads using the bulk posting API. I have tested all kind of things by including the manage url, including the live ad url etc. Nothing seems to work.